# Why does the result of scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum() change its type to numpy matrix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to generate a large sparse matrix and sum it but I encounter `MemoryError` a lot. So I tried the operation via [scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum) instead but found that the type of data changed back to a numpy `matrix` after taking the sum.

```
window = 10    
np.random.seed = 0
mat = sparse.csc_matrix(np.random.rand(100, 120)>0.5, dtype='d')
print type(mat)
>>> <class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>

mat_head = mat[:,0:window].sum(axis=1)
print type(mat_head)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
```

So I generated `mat` as zeros matrix just to test the result when `mat_head` is all zeros.

```
mat = sparse.csc_matrix((100,120))
print type(mat)
>>> <class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>
mat_head = mat.sum(axis=1)
print type(mat_head)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
print np.count_nonzero(mat_head)
>>> 0
```

Why does this happen? So sum via `scipy.sparse` is not benefited for preserving memory than `numpy` as they change the data type back anyway?

Comment: Because the result of that operation is not a sparse matrix anymore

Comment: @iacolippo I tested by generating all zeros matrix and sum. The data type of result is changed to numpy anyway.

Comment: how many zeros in your `mat_head`?

Comment: @hpaulj In my real data, I have 95591 zeros in `mat_head.shape = (115100,1)`. In the question, they are none of zeros (upper) and all zeros (lower) examples.

Comment: A row or column sum is calculated with a matrix product using a suitable  row or  column vector of ones.  You could test this yourself and see.if making that sparse is any faster or  easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm aware that your question of "why" mostly targets the motivation behind the design decision, but anyway I tracked down how the result of `csc_matrix.sum(axis=1)` actually becomes a numpy `matrix`.

The [`csc_matrix` class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/csc.py#L19) inherits from the [`_cs_matrix` class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/compressed.py#L22) which inherits from the [`_data_matrix` class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/data.py#L21) which inherits from the [`spmatrix` base class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/base.py#L64). This last one [implements `.sum(ax)` as](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/base.py#L1007-L1015)

```
if axis == 0:
    # sum over columns
    ret = np.asmatrix(np.ones(
        (1, m), dtype=res_dtype)) * self
else:
    # sum over rows
    ret = self * np.asmatrix(np.ones((n, 1), dtype=res_dtype))
```

In other words, [as also noted in a comment](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/base.py#L990-L992), the column/row sums are computed by multiplying with a dense row or column matrix of ones, respectively. The result of this operation will be a dense matrix which you see on output.

While some of the subclasses override their `.sum()` method, as far as I could tell this only happens for the `axis=None` case, so the result which you see can be attributed to the above block of code.

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid multiplication with dense array of ones? I'd like to get a sparse vector as a result, too.

Comment: @linello sorry, I put multiple mistakes in my previous comment. Let's try again. You can replicate what the library does but instead of `np.asmatrix` you can create a sparse column vector. So something like `aux = sparse.csc_matrix(np.ones((mat.shape[1], 1), dtype=mat.dtype)); summed = mat @ aux`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as it is possible to give a hard reason for what is essentially a design choice I'd make the following argument:

The csr and csc formats are designed for sparse but not extremely sparse matrices. In particular, for an nxn matrix that has significantly fewer than n nonzeros these formats are rather wasteful because on top of the data and indices they carry a field indptr (delineating rows or columns) of size n+1.

Therefore assuming a properly utilized csc or csr matrix it is reasonable to expect row or column sums not to be sparse and the corresponding method should return a dense vector.

Answer (score 1):

The `csr` and `csc` formats were developed for linear algeba, especially the solution of large, but sparse, linear equations

```
A*x = b
x = b/A
```

`A` must be invertible, and can't have all 0's rows or columns.

`A.sum(1)` is done by matrix multiplication, with a (n,1) array of 1s.

With your `mat`:

```
In [203]: np.allclose(mat*np.mat(np.ones((120,1))), mat.sum(1))
Out[203]: True
```

Doing that myself is actually a bit faster (overhead somewhere?)

```
In [204]: timeit mat.sum(1)
92.7 µs ± 111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [205]: timeit mat*np.mat(np.ones((120,1)))
59.2 µs ± 53.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I could also do this with a sparse matrix:

```
In [209]: mat*sparse.csc_matrix(np.ones((120,1)))
Out[209]: 
<100x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [211]: np.allclose(mat.sum(1),_.todense())
Out[211]: True
```

But the time is slower, even if I move the sparse creation outside the loop:

```
In [213]: %%timeit I=sparse.csc_matrix(np.ones((120,1)))
     ...: mat*I
     ...: 
215 µs ± 401 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If `mat` was `(115100,10)` with lots of all 0 rows, this all sparse approach could give both time and space savings.

---

`mat[:,:10]` is also performed with matrix multiplication, with a sparse extractor matrix.

It is actually slower than the row sum:

```
In [247]: timeit mat[:,:10]
305 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [248]: timeit mat[:,:10].sum(1)
384 µs ± 9.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I can combine the column selection with sum using:

```
In [252]: I = sparse.lil_matrix((120,1),dtype=int); I[:10,:]=1; I=I.tocsc()
In [253]: I
Out[253]: 
<120x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [254]: np.allclose((mat*I).todense(),mat[:,:10].sum(1))
Out[254]: True
```

Timing on this `mat*I` is slower, though I could improve the `I` construction step.

```
I = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(10,int), np.arange(10), np.array([0,10])), shape=(120,1))
```